# Shadowing a Doctor

Tags: lifestyle, practice-of-medicine

My doctor has allowed me to shadow him. As an aspiring med student, I'd no doubt relish the opportunity. I've obtained his availability from the secretary (for simplicity let's say: May 15-19 and June 12-17).

Should I request to shadow him for all of these shifts or would that be overboard? I'm asking because I don't want to be too much of a burden.

To all doctors and medical staff out there: what would be the optimal amount of time for a student to shadow you? how willing are you to take on a student?